# Can't read an XML file

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to make a simple read from an XML file in my .NET project.

I will share some code maybe someone will help me figure it out what I am doing wrong

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key = "connection" value="Data Source=(local); Initial Catolog = Airline_Reservation; Integrated Security=SSPI"/>    
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

my class:

```
public partial class AirlineReservation : Form
    {
    public SqlConnection connection;

    public AirlineReservation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string conexiune = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("connection");
            this.connection = new SqlConnection(@conexiune);
        }
}
```

When I try to run it I get this `Keyword not supported: 'initial catolog'.` on this row `this.connection = new SqlConnection(@conexiune);`

Any sugestions?

Comment: "catolog" is not correct english. "catalog" is, though.

Comment: Oh God I can't belive this..I'm sory for this stupid question

Answer (score 1):

The correct connection string should be:

```
<add key = "connection" value="Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog = Airline_Reservation; Integrated Security=SSPI"/>
```

The keyword is `Initial Catalog` and not `Initial Catolog` as you wrote. Please refer to the following website for more example on correct connection strings: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/